# Valid Parentheses LEETCODE edge case not passing test

Tags: c++

My code works on the normal test cases such as (), ()[]{}, but in the question there is a case where it allows to return if it matches like so {[]}. So my way to solve this problem and I don’t know if this is efficient or fast, is too find the position of the bracket and then check in the length() - pos so it is essentially looking backwards and seeing if it matches the first bracket. Here is my code below. Please let me know If I am working in the right direction, and if this is an efficient solution.

```
class Solution {
public:
bool isValid(string s) {
    stack<int> s1;
    size_t pos = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        s1.push(s[i]);
        
        if(s1.top() == '(' && s[i+1] != ')')            {  
            pos = s.find(s1.top());
            
            if(s1.top() != s.length() - (pos + 1) ) return false;
        }
        
        if(s1.top() == '{' && s[i+1] != '}') {
            pos = s.find(s1.top());
            if(s1.top() != s.length() - (pos  + 1) ) return false;
        }
        
        if(s1.top() == '[' && s[i+1] != ']') {
            pos = s.find(s1.top());
            if(s1.top() != s.length() - (pos + 1) ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

};

Comment: [I can't even compile your code!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c92923d788fdcb5)

Comment: You are working in a galaxy far, far away from the right direction.

Comment: @austinvan295, The first thing I notice is this line in your code "if(s1.top() == '(' && s[i+1] != ')') ". This line may cause your application to crash (segmentation fault) because the index [i+1] may go out of bound, i.e. it may go 1 character beyond the max length of the string.

Comment: The way you are using that `stack` you could replace it with a single `int` variable and it would do the same thing. You should use a stack for the solution, but actually use it. (take a look at the pop() method)

Comment: @austinvan295, Your code does not have the code to handle the cases of nested brackets such as {[]}. To fix it, you should only push the "open brackets" such as "(, [, { " into the stack. Then, you continue to iterate through the array, and when you find a close bracket such as "), ], }", you will try to match that "close bracket" with the top element of the stack... That is just my general idea, and there are more details in the logic

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Okay I got the pushing the opening brackets ONLY into the stack, but what happens when the closing bracket isn’t next to the opening bracket? Let’s say the this bracket ‘{‘ is second in the string and the ‘}’ is in the second to last. How can I detect that and make sure it is valid.

Comment: @austinvan295, Suppose the input is { ( [  ] ) }. Then first, you push 3 opening brackets into the stack. Next, when you see the first closing bracket, you pop the top opening bracket out of the stack to compare : if they do not match, you return FALSE. Then, you do the same thing for the next 2 closing brackets. After that, the input array is empty and the stack is empty. So, you conclude that the input array contains matching patterns, and return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Just use stack to push the opening bracket and check the top when you encounter a closing bracket.
Don't try to check i and i+1 positions at the same time. That would fix your code.

Comment: Okay I got that but what happens when the closing bracket is at the end of the string and not next to the character?

Comment: Then the top of the stack won't match.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code example that will help solve your problem:

```
boolean isBalanced(String str) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{') {
                stack.push(c);
            } else if (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}') {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                char top = stack.pop();
                if ((c == ')' && top != '(') || (c == ']' && top != '[') || (c == '}' && top != '{')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
}
```